# Does anyone know why R keeps turning my Plot into a list?

Tags: r

R keeps putting this function as a list instead of a plot. Does anyone know why?

```
unemp_jolts_plot <- ggplot() +
geom_line(data = new_melt.df, size=1.15, aes(x=date, y=value, color = variable)) + 
labs(title= "Unemployment and Job Openings",                                                                                  x= NULL, y=NULL, caption = "Source: BLS")+ 
theme_bw() +
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y"), breaks='2 years',limits = c(min, max))
theme(legend.position = c(.50, .97), legend.justification = c(0, 1), legend.text = element_text(size=14),legend.background=element_blank())
```

I have tried to use the print and view function, but this keeps coming up.
[image]

Comment: What do you get with `plot(unemp_jolts_plot)`?

Comment: it says this, Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'variable' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This means that you don't have a variable called `variable` in the `new_melt.df` data frame. Check `names(new_melt.df)` carefully, and ensure you aren't missing and capital letters, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. In the new melt df I have just this piece of code.   new_melt.df <- melt(new.df, id="date"). This code comes from a copy paste of a professor and he included variable, but I just want to be able to see the plot without it coming up as a list. Again, thank you so much for your assistance.